# Where do Lightsabers originate from?

Tags: star-wars

My question is fairly simple. I can't seem to find any canon source on this, so I thought I'd ask it.

Where do Lightsabers originate? And who was the first to create one?

Comment: Disney canon only or EU/Legends?

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't spot this; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber

Comment: Any canon answer really. I have read that page @Richard, but it doesn't seem to describe _where_ the tradition was first created, and anybody that was first involved in this tradition.

Comment: In the book Dawn of the Jedi: Into the Void they use metal swords imbued with the force which are as precious as light sabers. None of the books really go into lightsaber development unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Legends EU, starting with the Jedi's predecessors, the [Je'daii Order](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Je%27daii_Order), there were [Force-imbued blades](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force-imbued_blade), which were later replaced with [Forcesabers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Forcesaber), whose technology then lead to [Protosabers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Protosaber), which finally evolved into lightsabers.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I was looking for, thankyou. I also found [this](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/First_Blade) thanks to your links, which is essentially the first ever Lightsaber proper. So it looks like all my questions are pretty much answered.