# Why does Luke’s saber call to Rey?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I used to think that lightsabers were just inanimate objects, and I don't remember seeing anything like the scene in the basement of Maz Kanata's castle when Luke's lightsaber "calls" to Rey and shows her that vision.

Is there a canon explanation to this? Has anything similar been done in other canon or Legends material?

Comment: This is not currently answerable. It might be answered in Episode VIII.

Comment: I think all we can say at this point is that it was the will of the Force. More will doubtless be revealed in Episode VIII.

Answer (score 7):

There may be any of a few reasons:

1. > Rey may be Luke's daughter, or some relation to Luke, so the Lightsaber feels a familiar life force in Rey, don't forget that in canon, Lightsabers contain force that is imbued by it's owner.
2. > Rey may be a former Padawan of Luke, and because of this, essentially again feels a familiar life force.
3. > The Force itself reacted, and decided that Rey must come across the Lightsaber, just like it did when creating Anakin (in EU/Legends Anakin's creation was the force acting *against* Plagueis and Sidious).

Comment: Fixed your formatting, and I also weakened some of your statements; (1) and (2) are fan theories with limited canon support at the moment, so it seemed unfair to be so definitive

Comment: Looking at it after the edit I understand what you mean, I wasn't saying they were true, but just possible reasons floating around at the moment. The edit makes that much clearer, thanks :)

Comment: In Ref to 2, Rey seems surprised that she is a Jedi and does not appear to believe in the force. She may be hiding but she did seemed genuinely surprised by the events of Kantata's castle.

Comment: Personally, and this is conjecture because nobody knows, I believe that "The Force Awakens" is related to Rey's dormant knowledge of the force. Throughout the film she seems curiously interested in the force and the Jedi, and her vision seems to show that she was somehow involved in Ben's fall and protected from it. It's possible that when something dis-pleasurable happens to you as a child, you forget things. She could have early training from Luke.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: @PStag - there's a fan theory (which is somewhat out there, but does fit a lot of observed inconsistencies) that she was a padawan BUT was brainwashed into forgetting that. Wouldn't put it past Abrams to do that.

Comment: The downvote is mine, due to rampant speculation on a question that essentially *can't* have a definitive answer short of Abrams spilling the beans to the public, and because points 1 and 2 are also factually inaccurate. 1. Lightsabers don't "contain force"; they contain kyber crystals that can help attune a Force sensitive's attachment to the Force. 2. Rey thinks Luke is a myth, so she's not a former Padawan. Even if she were, so was Kylo, so why wouldn't it respond to him when he was at the castle, and why did it fly to her instead of him during the snowy fight on the Starkiller base?

Comment: @TylerH 1. Lightsabers were developed from force-imbued blades, see [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111494/where-do-lightsabers-originate-from) question. And 2. The vision Rey receives in the castle implies that she does in fact have some involvement in Kylo Ren's fall to the dark side. It's entirely possible that she was either brainwashed or simply forgot those memories as a child because they were bad. And re the down vote, the answer has been carefully edited abeit not by me, to make sure this _isn't_ rampant speculation. I feel your down vote is unfair.

Comment: @JohnBell That's Legends, so not canon, and lightsabers are not the same thing as force sabers or proto sabers. As for Rey's vision, you seem to be inferring that, but the vision I saw didn't imply that she was involved with Kyle Ren's path to the dark side whatsoever. It only showed that, thanks to out of universe film techniques like foreshadowing and the obvious point of her being the protagonist of the story, she is likely to be involved in his ultimate *downfall*.

Comment: Re: the edit, it was only edited to make it clear that you are giving suggestions, not facts, which actually strengthens the case that this is just speculation. As Jason Baker said, 1 and 2 are *fan theories*. And 3 is just a guess, though the most plausible of the 3 suggestions.