# Any canon precedents of Psychometry that Rey's visions are also Psychometry?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, rey

This sort of relates to this question, [Why does Luke’s saber call to Rey?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113478/why-does-luke-s-saber-call-to-rey), but it does not answer why Rey gets a flashback when she instantly touches the Lightsaber? Does the the Light-saber have something like a memory from who has used it? Or is it just touching a LightSaber brings back memories like any ordinary person does with something like smell and an old song they listened too when they were young?

EDIT: I would like this reopened and have a chance to respond by answering this question, as I think I have a I have an a canonical answer which is not based on opinion.

In [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Psychometry) it states that Psychometry is the force behind what Rey experienced,

> Psychometry was the Force ability of deducing information about people or events associated with an object solely by touching it. Whoever used that ability received input from sight, sound, and emotions. At the time of the Clone Wars, the Jedi Master Quinlan Vos was known for being proficient in psychometry, which made him an expert tracker. However, the Jedi Order did not approve of their members using psychometry to handle weapons of violence. The Order feared that, as the wielder's emotions could be sensed, the Jedi using his psychometric skill could be exposed to the dark side of the Force.

Comment: voting to close based on our [future works policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5187/5184).

Comment: POB because this is unprecedented and we simply do not know at this time (if we ever will). Also, what I just said is the answer; not a close reason.

Comment: @phantom42, I would really appreciate if you could re-look over the edited part in my question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why this one is closed and the other one isn't (and why it wasn't closed as a dupe of it instead).

Comment: @Mazura, technically , it is not a dupe, as the other question asks why she was called to it. Not why it showed her visions.

Comment: I see. That's as 'unanswerable' as this is then. Or at least *that* should be closed "based on our future works policy."

Comment: @Mazura, check my meta post here, I ansered the question I believe.http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9575/shouldnt-this-tfa-question-be-re-opened-so-it-can-be-answered

Comment: *By what canon mechanism could Rey have received visions by touching a lightsaber?*

Comment: "could suggest" is asking people to correlate. Both questioners and askers are redistricted to the facts. Conclusions are to be drawn only by the reader.

Comment: @Mazura, I see what you mean. Thanks.